# How do I use scope apply or run functions upon success in Angular 8 jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular

For reasons I will not get into here I am using jQuery ajax instead of Angular's http. As such I am doing an ajax call to my php server. However one problem is that upon either success or error, anything that is executed within the success/error blocks are limited to themselves. I cannot get the code in there to interact with any other variables or functions outside the ajax call.

I saw on an AngularJS thread that I am supposed to run $scope.apply however $scope does not exist for Angular jQuery apparently.

Here is my code:

jqueryAjaxEngine(prockey, sData) {

```
const DATA = 'prockey=' + prockey + sData;

console.log(DATA);
$.ajax({
  data:     DATA,
  url:      this.controllerUrl,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  type:     'POST',

    beforeSend: function(m) {
      if (m && m.overrideMimeType) {
        m.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        }
    },

    success: function(data) {

      console.log(data);

      // the this.returnData is constricted to within this block, after this block 
      // this.returnData is null
      this.returnData = data;

      console.log(this.returnData);
      this.succStatus = data.status;
      // They tell me that setSwitch does not exist, however it is a function on my file
      this.setSwitch(prockey, data);

    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
      console.log(xhr);
      this.returnData = xhr;
      console.log(this.returnData);
      this.succStatus = xhr.status;
  }
});
// this.setSwitch(data)

console.log(this.returnData);
return this.returnData;};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of scoping issues. In es6 you can use the arrow function which will make your life easier, meaning `this` will refer to the outer scope from which the arrow function was called. So you would write out your code as follows:

```
 success: data => {

  console.log(data);

  // the this.returnData is constricted to within this block, after this block 
  // this.returnData is null
  this.returnData = data;

  console.log(this.returnData);
  this.succStatus = data.status;
  // They tell me that setSwitch does not exist, however it is a function on my file
  this.setSwitch(prockey, data);

},
```